# Magento 1.9 : How to add video in product image gallery

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images

I have created product attribute name is video. But, I want to display video in product image gallery in product page.

Comment: Can you provide some things you have tried? Have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using , you can get that data & use this code in your `view.phtml` file

```
<iframe width="100%" height="auto" src="<?php echo $_product-> 
 getData('video'); ?>" frameborder="1" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Like this :

[image]

Comment: thanks for helping ... but where to add this code in view.phtml file

Comment: after getGalleryImages() foreach loop

Comment: Please check image you'll get idea where you need to add.

Comment: My pleasure @pramod24. please accept and upvote answer. So, other user can use this solution :)

Comment: let me know..if it's working or not..? if it's useful then please upvote & accept answer. so, it's useful to other user also @Pramod24